# Communicating with Agilent 4156A through PyVISA

Tags: python-2.7, serial-port, usb

I am currently trying to get any sort of response from my Agilent 4156A through RS232, but I can't seem to get anything. I have tried to set everything correctly, but I can't seem to get it to work. I am running it through a usb to RS232 connector. On the Agilent I set:

- BAUD RATE 38400
- DATA BITS 8
- PARITY None
- STOP BIT(S) 1

and I can not change the TRANSMIT PACING which is set to HARDWIRE. This is what I have so far

```
>>>import visa
>>>from visa import constants
>>>rm = visa.ResourceManager('@py')
>>>test = rm.open_resource('ASRL/dev/ttyUSB0::INSTR')
>>>test.baud_rate = 38400
>>>test.stop_bits = constants.StopBits.one
>>>test.parity = no_parity
>>>test.query('*IDN?')
```

And then it hangs at this query.

Comment: Did you tested with hyperteminal (windows) ?  with few Baud Rates ?? first try 9800. Have you RS232 convertor to USB ? I had hard time with one usb convertor.

Comment: Why are you passing `@py` to `ResourceManager`? What is the output of `rm.list_resources()`?